# Show the series $\sum (2^{1/n}-1)$ diverges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How to show that the series
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty (\sqrt[n]{2}-1)$$
diverges ?

Comment: Any n-th root of 2 will always be greater than 1.

Comment: This old question and [this other old question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2077654/does-the-series-sum-limits-n21-n-1-converge) are basically duplicates.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Observe that 
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{2n}\right)^n=\sum\limits_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}\frac{1}{2^in^i}$$
and that for $i\ge 1$ we have $\binom{n}{i}\le n^i$ so this becomes
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{2n}\right)^n\le 1+\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{2^{i}}<2$$
and thus we have 
$$\sqrt[n]{2}>1+\frac{1}{2n}$$
which gives us
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (\sqrt[n]{2}-1)\ge\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2n}=\infty.$$

Answer (score 11):

Hint:
$$2^{1/n}-1=e^{\frac{1}{n}\log 2}-1\sim \frac{1}{n}\log 2.$$

Comment: Nice, but better use $e^x\geq 1+x$ instead of $\approx$.

Comment: @ElmarZander Your inequality is usefull in our case of divergence, but by equivalence relation we can prove both divergence and convergence in different situation.

Answer (score 2):

$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{2^x-1}{x} = \log2$. This implies $\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{2^\frac{1}{n}-1}{\frac{1}{n}} = \log2$. Since the series $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n}$ is divergent, so by Comparison test (limit form), the series $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} (\sqrt[n]{2}-1)$ is divergent.

Comment: Please use Latex to format your post

Comment: [MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for future reference. Nice and quick proof btw (+1)