# Does the series $\sum\limits_n(2^{1/n} - 1)$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (2^{1/n} - 1)=(2^1 - 1) + (2^{\frac{1}{2}} - 1)+ ... +(2^{\frac{1}{n}}-1)+...$ converge?

I feel like it diverges the same way as $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ diverges: very slow, on a logarithmic scale.

Comment: Good intuition! Why do you think $2^{1/n}-1$ and $1/n$ ought to behave similarly? If you can formalise this idea, you're very close to a proof

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your intuition is correct!

Using the fact that $e^x-1 \ge x$ for all real $x$, we have $2^{\tfrac{1}{n}}-1 = e^{\tfrac{1}{n}\ln 2}-1 \ge \dfrac{1}{n}\ln 2$ for all $n$.

Then, since $\displaystyle\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n}\ln 2$ diverges, $\displaystyle\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}2^{\tfrac{1}{n}}-1$ diverges by direct comparison.

Comment: Nice answer (+1)

Comment: (+1)  This is the way I would have presented.  Happy Holidays Jimmy.  -Mark

Comment: (+1) What a nice answer, how did you know that fact about the $e^x-1$? Is it like a logical thing or a theorem somewhere?

Comment: @TehRod It follows from the Maclaurin series expansion of $e^x$.

Comment: Ah ok that makes perfect sense, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Your series and the harmonic series are asymptotically equivalent, as
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^{1/n}-1}{1/n}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2^x-1}{x}=\ln2
$$

Answer (score -1):

You can also go about this problem by using the Comparison Test:

Let $\sum$ $a_n$, $\sum$ $b_n$ be 2 positive sequences where $a_n$ $\le$ $b_n$. $$\\$$
$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (2^{1/n} - 1)$ $\ge$ $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)$

Since every infinite sum of a non-zero constant diverges, $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)$ diverges. Thus $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (2^{1/n} - 1)$ diverges.

Comment: You're missing the rest of the comparison test. But you've also misapplied it. The rightmost sum diverges to $-\infty$, so you've shown that the OP's sum either converges or diverges (either to $+\infty$ or it will cycle).

Comment: This can only be used when $b_n$ is positive